# How to resolve conflicting mod_rewrite rules and conditions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, expressionengine

I have a couple of rewrite rules in my .htaccess that seem to be conflicting.

I am running an ExpressionEngine (CodeIgniter) website that resolves all URI's using an index.php file. I have removed the index.php from the URI's for aesthetic reasons.

What I am trying to achieve:

- Redirect 301 all pages with a trailing slash (example.com/bla/ =>
  example.com/bla)
- Remove index.php from all URI's

What I have now:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=::1
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond $1 !^(images|system|themes|index\.php|admin\.php|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|humans\.txt|crossdomain\.xml) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
 </IfModule>
```

What works:

- All deeplinks are redirected to their non-trailing-slash version
  (example.com/bla/ => example.com/bla).
- index.php is removed from all deeplink pages.

What does not work:

- The homepage (example.com) gives me an error in Google Chrome, saying "Too many redirects".

How do I update the conditions and rules so that I achieve clean links without a trailing slash, and without index.php, regardless of which page it is.

Comment: What if you replace `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]` with `RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`?

Comment: Go to config.php then change $config['url_suffix'] = '';

Answer (score 1):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=::1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php(/.*)?$ /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(images|system|themes|index\.php|admin\.php|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|humans\.txt|crossdomain\.xml) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: With this solution, the redirect loop still exists for the homepage. `example.com` redirects me to `example.com/index.php`, and `example.com/index.php` redirects me to `example.com`. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try my updated rules after clearing your browser cache.